# How to make Django send request itself

Tags: django, celery

I need to make GET request, that executes himself once per 3 day, I found things about celery and Redis, but I don't understand how to send request. I mean, if I use celery, I need to wrap function with @app.task, so it can't be method GET of a class, right? And so I can't use method of a class outside of class, cause I don't have self (instance of a class). So how do I make Django send request to itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that Celery and Redis is probably too big for your question.

If you can, make a [custom django command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/). Then you can run that from crontab.

If it has to be a GET request, make a [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) script with [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) to your endpoint. And run that script from [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).